# Remove rows containing a specific character string in column with mostly NA

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data.frame in R which looks like this:

```
df<- data.frame("x" = c(1,4,5,7,4,32,2,5), "y"=c(NA,NA,"1", NA, "2", "1", NA, NA))
df$y <- as.character(df$y)
```

and I want to get rid of all rows, that contain a "1" or "2" in the column $y without dropping rows containing NAs (which are all others).

```
df[df$y!="1",]
```

sets all values NA that contain a NA or a "1" in the column.

Comment: `df[!df$y %in% c(1, 2), ]` ?

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. But why c(1,2) and not c("1","2")?